# Is it possible to import CAD model files into LTspice?

Tags: ltspice, pspice, orcad, cadence, cad

There are very beneficial and comprehensive collections of CAD models provided by Mouser or other websites. Is it possible to use them in LTspice?

Comment: _"...CAD models provided by mouser..."_ - example?

Comment: provided or collected or referenced. anyway. symbol, footprint, and 3d models are available.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. LTspice cannot use 3D models - it has no 3D view.
2. LTspice cannot use the footprint - has no PCB layout.
3. LTspice might conceivably be able to use the symbol, but I don't know of any way to import just the drawing.

LTspice needs the spice model, and a mapping between the pins and the model innards.

The CAD models won't provide the spice model, so they aren't of much use in LTspice.

Comment: thanks for your response; yes obviously LTspice does not support 3d and footprint models, as you said. but I meant importing the OrCAD capture schematics models into LTspice. is it possible?

Comment: No, it is not possible to import .DSN files of OrCAD in to LTspice

Comment: by the way, are the OrCAD capture schematic models available on mouser or ultra librarian? if not, is there any straightforward and comprehensive website containing spice models?

Comment: @Kamran: Your question doesn't mention OrCAD.  OrCAD appears to use [PSpice models](https://resources.orcad.com/schematic-capture-circuit-simulation/quick-tutorial-the-new-pspice-model-search) rather than some proprietary format, so you could use the [PSpice models in LTspice.](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/397354/how-can-i-convert-pspice-model-into-ltspice-model/397365)

Comment: @JRE: I said CAD models. doesn't it contain OrCAD capture?

Comment: Yes, but it also includes [dozens of other packages.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_EDA_software)