Trouble Adding PSpice Model to LTSpice
I am trying to simulate the PSpice model found here: https://www.ti.com/product/UCC25800-Q1#design-tools-simulation
From looking through various forms I was able to create a symbol from the .subckt directive found in the .LIB file, but the content of the file doesn't seem to be valid. I am receiving this error.
"
Will it be possible to import this component into PSpice? Or would it be possible to use the .sxsch file? Any help is appreciated.

Not sure if these will be of any help but you can check. https://www.onethesis.com/how-to-create-an-ltspice-model-from-pspice-or-tina-ti-model/    https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/397354/how-can-i-convert-pspice-model-into-ltspice-model

Duplicate of this question? UCC25800 PSpice model

This model is encrypted such that it can't be read by any software other than PSPICE. You will not be able to use it with LTspice, ngspice, or any other simulator.
Both the with-sync and without-sync models appear to be encrypted.
You can email a TI rep to ask for an unencrypted model, and they may be willing to give you one, but I wouldn't count on it.

Here's a reference which supports the "I wouldn't count on it" part:  https://e2e.ti.com/support/power-management-group/power-management/f/power-management-forum/1228988/ucc25800-q1-lt-spice-model-for-simulation-purpose

And here's a stackexchange Q/A discussing the chances at being able to hack the AES 256 bit encryption used.
